# API endpoint returns text before and after the JSON content, causing parsing error

Tags: json, rest, api, http, postman

I'm using postman to test calling a rest service endpoint.

I'm trying to parse the JSON return content but it throws an error because the response body has more than just JSON.

This is how I parse it in my postman test script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

Here is the response body:

```
--13398550-b6ea-4731-a8ee-4b2ad24c3cfe
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

//this is the actual content I want to parse --->
{"id":"123456","value":"the_value"}

--13398550-b6ea-4731-a8ee-4b2ad24c3cfe--
```

When I try to parse it, I get the following error (in postman)

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected number in JSON at position 3

Obviously because the content being parsed is not just JSON

Is this something special that the api is doing? Or am I just parsing it incorrectly?

NOTE: I'm not including details of the rest service function. If the cause of this issue is something that is being done by the service itself, then that is enough of an answer for me to perhaps ask another question or do some further investigation. The purpose of this question is to ask **whether this is something special being done in HTTP, or if it's the service.**

Edit:

I managed to see the server side code and it is indeed manually building the response with boundaries identified by a GUID. I'll have to manually parse the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is not emitting straight up application/json, it's packed in a multipart mime envelope.

Whether or not it's doing that correctly depends on the response headers. If you didn't expect a multipart response, but a simple JSON response, then I'd say yes: it's something you need to fix server-side.

Comment: Great this is what I wanted to know, I will have to find out what the server is doing

Comment: Or perhaps find out if I can parse multi part responses in postman

Comment: I agree, either could be a viable outcome. It's not necessarily wrong. I will say that it's unusual though for a typical API. Multipart stuff is only used in a small amount of situations